# Logging in ethereum private blockchain

Tags: private-blockchain, nodes, logs

How to create a log file of node activity ?

Is it possible to track nodes activity(sending transaction,finding transactions,mining new blocks)?

How to track which nodes are connected/disconnected,time of its activity?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

from the [documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Getting-Geth) :

> Output from the console can be logged or redirected:
>
> geth console 2>>geth.log
>
> Using standard tools, the log can be monitored in a separate window:
>
> tail -f geth.log
>
> Alternatively, you can also run one terminal with the interactive
>   console and a second one with the logging output directly.
>
> Open two terminals In the second terminal type tty. The output will be
>   something like /dev/pts/13 In your main terminal, type: geth console
>   2>> /dev/pts/13 This will allow you to monitor your node without
>   cluttering the interactive console.

Comment: Is it possible to monitor users activities in Ethereum network(main chain)? and how?

Comment: monitor what exactly?

Comment: who sent and what transaction, who mined last block, who created contracts and what contracts

Comment: you need an explorer then : pending tx:https://etherscan.io/txsPending blocks miner : https://etherscan.io/blocks